# Aligning content side by side using div

Tags: html, css

I have two `div`. One `div` represent header content and other `div` represent details content. I want the content of both the `div` aligned side by side. The content of the right div (i.e. details) should always appear on right. If the detail content doesn't fit then `extra` content should appear in next line. Something like below where File4.pdf and File5.pdf doesn't fit so it goes to next line.

[image]

I was able to do this using `table` but i would like to use `div` instead of table. However using `div` when the content doesn't fit the whole content moves to next line.

here is the [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/494wrsyo/1/)

Comment: Have you tried display:flex or inline-block ?

Answer (score 1):

You would need a container for the right side elements, with the following style

```
float:left;
width:calc(100% - 222px); /*the -222px is the width of the left element + the padding + the margin*/
overflow:hidden;
```

---

Full updated example (*from provided jsfiddle*)

```css
dl {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
dl dt {
  float: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 2px;
  width: 200px;
}
dl dd {
  margin: 2px 0;
}
.details-container {
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% - 222px);
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div style="float:left;padding-right:20px;">
  <dl>
    <dt>Name:</dt>
    <dd>Foo Bar</dd>
    <dt>Date:</dt>
    <dd>01/04/2017</dd>
  </dl>
</div>
<div class="details-container">
  <div style="float:left">
    <dl>
      <dt>File Name:</dt>
      <dd>File1.pdf</dd>
      <dt>Page Count</dt>
      <dd>10</dd>
    </dl>
  </div>
  <div style="float:left">
    <dl>
      <dt>File Name:</dt>
      <dd>File2.pdf</dd>
      <dt>Page Count</dt>
      <dd>10</dd>
    </dl>
  </div>
  <div style="float:left">
    <dl>
      <dt>File Name:</dt>
      <dd>File3.pdf</dd>
      <dt>Page Count</dt>
      <dd>10</dd>
    </dl>
  </div>
  <div style="float:left">
    <dl>
      <dt>File Name:</dt>
      <dd>File4.pdf</dd>
      <dt>Page Count</dt>
      <dd>10</dd>
    </dl>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be more precise about what you want exactly, because there are many different ways to acheive this, depending on if you have a fixed number of elements per line for the 'details', if you want it to be responsive, or is a part of something else that is in a fixed-size element? Do you want scrolls to appear if any list in a div becomes too big?

Here are some clues:

- as said by Gaby aka G. Petrioli, you will most likely need a wrapper div around one or both of your divs to do what you want
- if the height of a line is fixed and you don't matter scrollbars when content gets to a new line, just set the height of both divs to the same value, with 'overflow:scroll'. You can choose if scrollbars are horizontal or vertical by using specifically 'overflow-x:scroll' or 'overflow-y:scroll'
- if you still have fixed height line but want the items that don't fit not to be shown, still define the dimensions, adding 'overflow:hidden'. This way all that is out of the wrapping div will disappear.
- when a dimension is set and not the other, like in Gaby aka G. Petrioli example, using 'overflow:hidden' can fix the fact that the wrapping div doesn't have its dimensions updated when floating content gets to a new line (provoking elements to sometimes overlap each other)
- if you want items to be forced to a certain number per line (with the content of each "tile" being forced to be resized or scrolled), you will need a layout with elements defined in %. This will be more tricky and need a more precise question to be fully answerable..

Answer (score 0):

FlexBox ??

```
<div class="container">
<div class="left">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <div class="value">Value asd asd as das d</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="right">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <div class="value">Value asd asd as</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <div class="value">Value adasd</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <div class="value">Value</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <div class="value">Value</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <div class="value">Value</div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

.container {
   display: flex;
 }

 .item {
   padding-bottom: 30px;
 }

  .container .left {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding-right: 50px;
  }
    .container .right {
      display: flex;
      width: 70%;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .container .right .item {
      width: 30%;
    }
```

Work example https://jsfiddle.net/494wrsyo/2/